# How to find shapes on image

Tags: math, imagemagick, gd

This is not related to any language atm, only math algorithm required. I have some image, lets say this one [image]

I need to cut tree [image] from this image, sky with clouds and grass should be threated as background. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "background" - some part of image around main object.

Comment: and, of course, the object is that part of the image that isn't the background...   I think belisarius was trying to ask: other than your interpretation of the meaning of the objects in the picture, what distinguishes background from foreground?  For example, how do we know in your picture that the lions aren't the object and, hence, the tree is the background.  To me, lions seem more interesting than trees.

Comment: I think it is still a valid question but I suspect the problem is very hard mathematically and algorithmically. One might ask instead for an algorithm that can identify "significant" distinct areas in a picture. A uselessly simple algorithm would be to just group all pixels of the same color as a "feature".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the algorithm that your looking for is "blob detection".  Here's a [video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZtHM9_sVyU).  Blob detection is implemented, for example, in OpenCV.

In general, though, as several people have pointed out in the comments, what one means by "object" needs to be defined by image properties and not image interpretation.  For example, in your image, are the "objects" the tress, lions, or clouds?  Trees are green blobs, clouds are white blobs, etc.