# java image white color extraction

Tags: java, image, postgresql, image-processing, postgis

how to extract each image with white color into separate sections as shown below?[image]

from the picture above, there will be nine separate section after the extract

I have tried several algorithms such as fillgrid but not exactly what I expected.

**so that I could store every sections into a PostGIS database as polygon geometry**

What algorithm can I use? 
or maybe there is a function in java or postgis library?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287267/how-to-find-shapes-on-image) may help you but I think you could do this by finding the differences in colour in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "polygonise" your raster data into vectors.

One such tool is from [GDAL](https://gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html), with a method originally in C++, but also has bindings to Java.

- [Java bindings (search for "Polygonize")](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html)
- [C API description of parameters for GDALPolygonize](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716151832/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1)

Some further hints on using the Polygonize method is that you will need to classify values of your raster as "NO DATA" values, then polygonise the remaining data portion. The resulting polygon can be placed in most geospatial vector formats, including a PostGIS database.

---

Another solution is to load the image into PostGIS raster, then use either [`ST_Polygon`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Polygon.html) or [`ST_DumpAsPolygons`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html) to do essentially the same task as GDALPolygonize, but with fewer options.